# cannot zip locked access file

Tags: powershell, ms-access

I am writing a powershell script which creates a zip file of a local folder:

```
   [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory('c:\myfolder\', 'c:\myarchive.zip', [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Fastest,$true)
```

This folder contains an MS-Access database. This database is opened at the same time by another user. I cannot ask him to close this database.

The zip operation fails because the database is locked. Is there a way to bypass this lock and make a copy of the database ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try doing this when the user is not around like at night via scheduled task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the folder to a temporary place and zip the copy.

Comment: Thanks but there is no way to do that without copying the full folder ?

Comment: You could loop thru all the files and add a all but the locked file to the zip archive and then copy the locked file to a temporary location and add that one too.